# AWS Lambda Boto3 "Unknown service: 'sqs'"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-sqs

I've just written a Python Lambda function which does some MySQL stuff and then sends a message off to SQS. This all works fine locally and the message is sent to SQS successfully.

I am creating an SQS Client like so:

```
sqsClient = boto3.client('sqs')
```

However, after deploying my packaged Lambda function to AWS and running the built-in Lambda test feature. I get the following error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unknown service: 'sqs'. Valid service names are: ",
  "errorType": "UnknownServiceError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/imp.py\", line 234, in load_module\n    return load_source(name, filename, file)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.7/imp.py\", line 171, in load_source\n    module = _load(spec)\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 696, in _load\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 677, in _load_unlocked\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>\", line 728, in exec_module\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/main.py\", line 20, in <module>\n    sqsClient = boto3.client('sqs')\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/boto3/__init__.py\", line 91, in client\n    return _get_default_session().client(*args, **kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/boto3/session.py\", line 263, in client\n    aws_session_token=aws_session_token, config=config)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/botocore/session.py\", line 838, in create_client\n    client_config=config, api_version=api_version)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/botocore/client.py\", line 79, in create_client\n    service_model = self._load_service_model(service_name, api_version)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/botocore/client.py\", line 117, in _load_service_model\n    api_version=api_version)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/botocore/loaders.py\", line 132, in _wrapper\n    data = func(self, *args, **kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/botocore/loaders.py\", line 378, in load_service_model\n    known_service_names=', '.join(sorted(known_services)))\n"
  ]
}
```

My initial thought was that maybe the Lambda version of boto3 doesn't include SQS yet. I don't think this is the issue though as I am deploying my own version of boto and botocore. I've also added the following lines in my function to ensure Lambda is using my deployed version of boto and and not it's inbuilt version:

```
print("boto3 version:"+boto3.__version__)
print("botocore version:"+botocore.__version__)
```

Which is outputting the following versions:

```
boto3 version:1.9.87
botocore version:1.12.87
```

These are correct and the same as my local versions.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT:**
I am using a batch file to deploy my code currently which is as follows:

```
powershell.exe -nologo -noprofile -command "& {& Remove-Item .\deploy -Force -Recurse }"
mkdir deploy
powershell.exe -nologo -noprofile -command "& {& Get-ChildItem .\src -Exclude '__pycache__' | Copy-Item -Destination .\deploy }"
cd deploy
pipenv lock -r > dependencies.txt
pip install -r dependencies.txt --no-deps -t .
powershell.exe -nologo -noprofile -command "& {& Get-ChildItem . -Exclude '__pycache__' | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath deploy.zip -Force }"
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name API-LogUserInterest --zip-file fileb://deploy.zip
echo Deployment finished!
pause
```

This is creating a "deploy" folder in my working directory, installing the dependencies there as well as copying my source code from a "src" folder. This whole deploy folder is then zipped using powershell and pushed to Lambda using the AWS CLI `update-function-code` command.

Here is a screenshot of the contents of the deploy.zip:

[image]

Comment: Interesting, maybe you can share a little more by what you mean by "deploying my own version of boto". I assume that means you're packaging these dependencies. Are you using SAM, Serverless, Chalice, etc? Seems the answer is probably in there since boto3 reports no known services.

Comment: @dmulter Yes, I am packing all dependencies along with my source code into a zip file and uploading. See edited question for the batch file I am using to do all of this.

Comment: By any chance, your local python version differs from lambda python version though I assume all the lambda python runtime environments are identical especially boto3 package

Comment: @omuthu My local version is 3.7.2 and the Lambda function is set to 3.7 (options in Lamba are 2.7, 3.6 or 3.7).

Comment: Ok, in that case, you should find this file under your botocore folder ./botocore/data/sqs/2012-11-05/service-2.json

Comment: @omuthu , yes that file is there.